# Using multiple computers as a processing and data storage cluster

Tags: virtual-machine, distributed-computing

I have about 17 or so old computers that by themselves can't do much, but I was wondering if there was any way to combine them so that they could run multiple VMs in a distributed way. For example, let's say I have 3 computers that each have 100 GB of HDD space, 2.0 GHz processor and 2 GB of memory. I'd want to run 2 VMs on that group of computers where each VM has 150 GB of HDD space, 3.0 GHz processor and 3 GB of memory. Is there any way to do such a thing?

Comment: to understand your possibilities read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing

Comment: A little off topic: at my university where I studied they made a super computer out of Xboxes because it was cheaper to make. They hacked the bios of the Xboxes and linked all of them together.